# Where is the mount point/folder for a USB pen drive mounted on Marshmallow?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, 6.0-marshmallow

Prior to Android Marshmallow, I used [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=en) to access my USB OTG pen drive.  When I tried it first time on my Nexus 5 I saw a native notification and notification from StickMount.

Stickmount usually mounts the pen drive as a folder under storage folder. This helped me to use my own file explorer and other apps.  However the stock notification has two buttons:
[image]

Upon touching `Explore`, a native browser opens and shows the file. I would like to use my own file explorer like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en).

By using the stock USB feature, I would like to know the mount point (the path) of the mounted drive. Does any know or tried this feature?

Device info: Nexus 5, Android 6.0, rooted with stock ROM.

Following is the output of the command `mount` in the terminal emulator after inserting the USB drive:

```
u0_a137@hammerhead:/ $ mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=750,gid=1000 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/default/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/read/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/write/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nomblk_io_submit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nomblk_io_submit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist /persist ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nomblk_io_submit,nodelalloc,errors=panic,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem /firmware vfat ro,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0337,dmask=0227,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /storage tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
tmpfs /storage/self tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
u0_a137@hammerhead:/ $
```

Comment: USB OTG works with ES File Explorer for me http://i.stack.imgur.com/hfndc.jpg

Comment: @Manubhargav, yes indeed this is even better!

Comment: Silly question but have you updated the App to the latest version(v4.0.2.9) after System update?and reboot the phone?

Answer (score 7):

`/mnt/media_rw/random-hex-id` is the path you're looking for, where 'random-hex-id' is a folder name of format `ABCD-EF01`, e.g. E4E4-4394. Guess it took a random to actually be useful. You must have access to root.

Comment: Do you not mean `/mnt/media_rw/random hex ID`?

Comment: The hex ID is [Volume Serial Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number) for use with FAT and NTFS file systems - see link for details. Not that it matters anyway.

Comment: Weird that you can see the external SD card without root but not the USB OTG drive mount point.

Comment: how do i get access to this folder without root?  my file explorer (Fx) says it's going to ask me for permission, but never does!

Comment: Well I'm having the exact same problem for a totally different reason, and I *still* can't get access... curse you Verizon!